# Custom container does not adjust correctly layout to in-call status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4

I am using my own custom container view controller that is modally 
presented from a root view controller (so the container is not the root view controller itself). Root view controller gets its layout handled properly when the in-call status bar is shown. Now if I modally present the custom container with its child (lets say instance of `SomeViewController`), the child is laid out as expected. If an in-call status bar is shown while the custom container is already presented, the child adjusts correctly.

The problem arises when the in-call status bar is shown while the custom container is not yet presented. If I present the custom container while there is an in-call status bar, the bottom of the child view gets cropped by the size of the extended status bar (i.e., 20 points) - it seems like either the size of the frame is not correct, or there is an offset set to it. If I dismiss in-call status bar, the top gets adjusted to the newly gained space, but the bottom stays cropped.

Following shows the relevant code of the container view:

```
class ContainerController: UIViewController {

    var selectedViewController: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let selectedViewController = selectedViewController {
            initialTransition(to: selectedViewController)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func initialTransition(to viewController: UIViewController) {
        guard self.isViewLoaded else {
            return
        }
        self.addChildViewController(viewController)
        viewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    // rest of the code omitted
}
```

The container view is presented using this code in the root view controller:

```
let container = ContainerController()
trainingContainer.selectedViewController = SomeViewController()
self.present(trainingContainer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

While there are several SO questions about similar issues ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112762/in-call-status-bar-unable-to-satisfy-constraints), [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595514/uiviewcontroller-in-call-status-bar-issue), etc.), most of them suggest either solutions that did not work (e.g., old [wantsFullScreenLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621390-wantsfullscreenlayout) and its successors), or seemed a bit too heavyweight (observing status bar did change to adapt layout), especially considering that when the child view controller was presented directly, it was behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I was able to determine that there was a problem with the frame being set - the frame of the container view controller seemed to be offseted but not resized when the `initialTransition(to:)` was called (in container's `viewDidLoad`), thus causing the child the get a frame that overlapped the bottom of the screen by the offset - 20 points.

My first approach was to add setting the frame once again in container's `viewDidAppear`, which in the end solved the problem, but cause a glitch - for a moment the bottom seemed cropped, and then `viewDidAppear` was called and the layout was adjusted correctly. This glitch looked bad.

I finally achieved what I wanted by overriding container's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and setting the frame of the child there (thus when the container gets notified to adjust its frame to the status bar, the information about a new frame gets passed to the child).

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.selectedViewController?.view.frame = self.view.frame
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```