# (Native Script) : Empty white line/space appearing on layout when sharing hotspot (ios blue bar)?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

If you take a look at this screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3XSY.jpg

You will notice a white space appearing between the regular nativescript layout and the IOS blue bar.

Im using a page-outlet and a stacklayout inside a component that's called form the outlet.

Im also using a TAB View, taken from the Tab View sample app.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

This white space DOES NOT appear when there is no blue bar.

Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595514/uiviewcontroller-in-call-status-bar-issue) is a similar issue reported, you might want to try the given solutions. If you are not familiar with marshalling native code, you may refer the [official docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview).

Comment: Thanks for the point Manoj. This issue is not when the blue bar appears and then disappears, is when the blue bar is in place. But I will explore the native "willChangeStatusBarFrame" method for sure