# Constraint errors when incoming call happens (UITextEffectsWindow - UIInputSetContainerView - ...)

Tags: ios, xcode

I meet in my project the following message when a incoming call happens...

---------------BEGIN LOG MESSAGE IN DEBUG AREA---------------

```
2015-11-12 18:19:16.707 test[75925:6804554] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fafbacbeba0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fafbacbca20]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fafbac12b20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fafbac04390 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fafbacbca20]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fafbac12b20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fafbacbeba0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fafbacbca20]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fafbac12b20 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

---------------END LOG MESSAGE IN DEBUG AREA---------------

Thus, I decided to deconstruct my view step by step until this message disappear to determine which constraint is responsible. I found nothing.

Actually, it happens also with an almost empty project.

For instance:

1. Create a new "Single View Application"
2. Select the Viewcontroller in Interface Builder
3. Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller
4. Build and Run
5. In Simulator: Hardware > Toggle In-Call Status Bar (cmd Y)

And you see the same problem.

Is it a bug from XCode or did I miss something?
(I work this XCode 7.0.1)

What have I to do with this?

In advance, thanks for your answers.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345816/20-uiinputsetcontainerview-constraint-breaks-when-call-in-status-bar-gets-v

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Call Status Bar (Unable to Satisfy Constraints)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112762/in-call-status-bar-unable-to-satisfy-constraints)