# Constraint conflict warning using openURL

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode7

Xcode 7.1.1, 7.2
Noticed when using openURL in an app (phone call). 
Added ids to all of my constraints regarding this VC and none show up as the ones with warnings.

```
func makeCall(theNumber: String) {
        if theNumber != "" {
            if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://" + theNumber) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }
        }
    }
```

Debug area shows:

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ea3670 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x15e87f90]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x15df11f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15d986a0 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x15e87f90]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x15df11f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ea3670 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x15e87f90]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x15df11f0 )>
```

Comment: Its not an apple bug. Its clearly said that, among those two constraint one is not needed and its conflicting at runtime. Am sure you need to remove any one constraint out of those two but to determine which constraint to be removed and what more constraints needs to be added instead of that to make the screen auto layout warning free in storyboard i need to look into your designed elements and constraints. can you post some screenshots or explanation of constraints used for all elements in the section?

Comment: In trying to chase this issue I added an id to every constraint in this VC - some are storyboard and some are programmed. I have tested if they show up when purposely adding a conflicting value. As you can see, the problem constraints do not show any added ids. I am not sure where these problem constraints are created. There is no custom keyboard etc. To clarify, the warning only occurs when a button is used to call makeCall() and the phone app opens.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal This must be an apple bug. I don't have any constraints on the view, I don't have a storyboard or even a nib-file and I'm still got this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, created a blank single view project with no added views/constraints (as described), toggled the simulator using command + y, and received the same constraint warnings.

[|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView constraint breaks when call-in status bar gets visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345816/20-uiinputsetcontainerview-constraint-breaks-when-call-in-status-bar-gets-v)