# Keyboard Constraint issue

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am not using a custom keyboard and I did not add ANY constraints on any of my elements in my view controller but I am still getting an error. The error comes up only when I tap in the textfield to enter information. The error is below:

2016-01-04 13:15:04.442 App[:] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d662d20 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x12e859230]   (Names: '|':UIRemoteKeyboardWindow:0x12e875520 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d75b1f0 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x12e859230]   (Names: '|':UIRemoteKeyboardWindow:0x12e875520 )>"
```

Please help

Comment: have you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false on your view?

Comment: I tried this for the various elements on the storyboard but it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled**

There is a good discussion and a solution of this issue found here:

[In Call Status Bar (Unable to Satisfy Constraints)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112762/4018041)

It has to do with various constraints that are enforced when additional windows are added to your window hierarchy, e.g. `UITextEffectsWindow` and `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow`.

It appears that this constrains error happens only the first time the in-call status bar is shown (this is most common), or in other scenarios involving the presentation of an additional custom window that would sit on top of the key window.

The original article on the Dev forums can be found here:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16375

Hope this helps!  Cheers.